# Summing over values in Google Sheets after applying a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of strings of the form

```
n|m
```

where n<m are natural numbers and I want to calculate the sum of this column where each cell has value m-n (m *minus* n). I can calculate the respective values into a separate cell via:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1,"|"), 0,2)-INDEX(SPLIT(A1,"|"), 0,1)
```

and sum over those but I would like to do it in one step just as one formula below the specified column in one cell. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in B1

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A,"|"), 0,2)-INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A,"|"), 0,1))))
```

if you want to get the sum below the last value, i.e. row#8

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFERROR(INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A8,"|"), 0,2)-INDEX(SPLIT(A1:A8,"|"), 0,1))))
```

Comment: May be `=ArrayFormula(SUM(INDEX(SPLIT(INDIRECT("A1:A"&(ROW()-1)),"|"), 0,2)-INDEX(SPLIT(INDIRECT("A1:A"&(ROW()-1)),"|"), 0,1))) `?

Comment: This seems to be working for me, I need a bit to understand the formula but thank you nonetheless!

Comment: Yes JohnSUN, good solution!

Comment: @MikeSteelson I actually meant the solution *you* posted, that is the one that's already working for me but of course JohnSUN's solution is also working. Thanks to both!